# Add javascript supplied form values to an options list

Tags: forms

I have a form, which the user inputs certain data into.
In the form is an empty, (and initially hidden) select list.

Once certain data has been entered, a javascript that polls the website, which in turn passes the poll request on to an external service. (This goes through the website so I don't have to give out the API-key to the user agent)

The external service returns a list of options. Currently these are passed back through the polled route, and returned to the javascript.

The javascript then constructs a select list for the user to chose from, and a form is then submitted with this choice.

The trouble with this is that when the original form is built, the select list is empty, and the submitted data is validated against this empty list, resulting in an "illegal choice"-error being displayed.

How do I allow this submission? My own thoughts:

1. Can I cause the form to rebuild during the polling process?
2. Can I force Drupal to ignore the validation of this particular field? (And add any manual validation as necessary?)
3. Can I move the data out to a plain text-field and just pretend the user submitted the empty value that the form was built with? I tried messing with the `$form_state->getValues()` array, but couldn't make this work.

Comment: You could use Form API Ajax. `#ajax` attached to the form element where the user inputs the initial data.  This rebuilds the form automatically. In that Ajax request the form build could then check for the triggering element to poll the external service and populate the select list.

Comment: @4uk4 I understand that Ajax will rebuild the form, but how does the new data get into the ajax call? Ajax functions take the same parameters as most other form api functions, that is the form array and a form state. Oh, are the new values available in the form state perhaps that's passed in to the function?

Comment: Yes, in an Ajax request your form class method `buildForm()` receives a $form_state object filled with the submitted values and the triggering element, if you need to know which form element caused the Ajax request.

Comment: You cannot insert form options with JS, as the server will reject them from valid. This is a major part of Drupal's security, and one reason it is difficult to hack. The way this is done is to request the options on the back end, with a server-side call, rather than a JS call.